# Basic page content not showing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I added a basic page that has a title and some body. But when I go to see it, there's no body content. But if I go to edit it, there it is!

Any ideas why? sorry, I'm a bit newbie on Drupal...

Drupal version: 7

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? If you are, we'd need to see your page.tpl.php / node.tpl.php / specific page/node template.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly, so I can check?

Comment: Ok, I think your comment drove me to the solution... Try to make an answer so I can vote you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure you are printing out the node/page content within the correct template, node.tpl.php/page.tpl.php